# read php file rendered html using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am just trying to read the file content of a rendering HTML of URL

Here the code i am using , its always going in error section .

```php
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://www.withholding32.com/api/wh32calc.php?userid=nick&fpp=12&ffs=Single&fa=0&fgp=6000&figp=0&fiytd=0&st=6&stp=6000&ss=Single&sa=0&sad=0&stca=0',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

but in case i run the same url directly in browser , its show me html.

[here is url](http://www.withholding32.com/api/wh32calc.php?userid=nick&fpp=12&ffs=Single&fa=0&fgp=6000&figp=0&fiytd=0&st=6&stp=6000&ss=Single&sa=0&sad=0&stca=0)

Comment: Change `type` to GET?

Comment: This is because you have Cross-Origin issue. If you check your errorThown, you will see: is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
   $('document').ready(function() {

      $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=' + 
      encodeURIComponent('http://www.withholding32.com/api/wh32calc.php?userid=nick&fpp=12&ffs=Single&fa=0&fgp=6000&figp=0&fiytd=0&st=6&stp=6000&ss=Single&sa=0&sad=0&stca=0') + '&callback=?',

      function(data){
         $("#result").html(data.contents);

       });

});
```

Refer : http://jsfiddle.net/R7EPt/275/

Answer (score 2):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/N7avm/4/)

You can use this in your head tag

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/IonicaBizau/jQuery-cross-domain-requests/master/js/jquery.xdomainajax.js">
</script>
```

### code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.withholding32.com/api/wh32calc.php?userid=nick&fpp=12&ffs=Single&fa=0&fgp=6000&figp=0&fiytd=0&st=6&stp=6000&ss=Single&sa=0&sad=0&stca=0', // Or your web page link
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
      var headline = res.responseText;
      $('body').append(headline);
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: I don't have control over php page .

Comment: @rahularyansharma I have updated with code and demo, Check it and respond.

Answer (score 0):

Change your request type to GET, all your parameters are given in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using post method for the ajax than you can't pass argument with url and also add control origin to your php file.

try this...

AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.withholding32.com/api/wh32calc.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        async:false,
        data: 'userid=nick&fpp=12&ffs=Single&fa=0&fgp=6000&figp=0&fiytd=0&st=6&stp=6000&ss=Single&sa=0&sad=0&stca=0',
        success: function(data) {
                    alert('success');
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('error');
        }
    });
```

PHP CODE:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: still error . i tried with both POST and GET . Is it possible for  you to create js fiddle for your answer.

Comment: Can you add 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

into "http://www.withholding32.com/api/wh32calc.php" than only my jsfiddle link will work

Comment: I don't have control over that Page . that page is basically a provider of API >